# Unable to call another function inside facebook login callback in vue2

Tags: vue.js, axios, facebook-javascript-sdk, asynccallback

I have a login with facebook system on my vue2 application. This captures the access token from FB API and sends to backend for handling user data.

While click on the login with facebook button it fetches access token properly but after that while i am making an axios call this is not getting post method. I tried to put the axios call in another method and call it after fetching token but then it shows that the method is not defined.

Here is my code

```
 async getUserData() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          this.fbLoginSubmit(response.authResponse.accessToken)
        }
      });
    },
fbLoginSubmit(token){
..... axios call here ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using arrow (=>) function instead for `getLoginStatus`?

```js
async getUserData() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      this.fbLoginSubmit(response.authResponse.accessToken)
    }
  });
},

fbLoginSubmit(token){
..... axios call here ......
}
```